# Google Guava Cache evicting entries for SIZE when no maxSize specified

Tags: java, guava

I am using the Google Guava `CacheBuilder` to create a `Cache` instance. My code looks something like the following:

```
return CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .initialCapacity(initialCapacity)
            .expireAfterAccess(expirationInterval, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .removalListener(LOGGING_AUTOEVICTION_ONLY_REMOVAL_LISTENER)
            .build();
```

My removal listener is, as the name implies:

```
private static final RemovalListener<MyKey, MyRecord>  LOGGING_AUTOEVICTION_ONLY_REMOVAL_LISTENER
        = new RemovalListener<MyKey, MyRecord>() {
            @Override
            public void onRemoval(RemovalNotification<MyKey, MyRecord objectObjectRemovalNotification) {
                if (objectObjectRemovalNotification.wasEvicted()) {
                    log.debug("Entry evicted from cache: {} - Reason: {}", objectObjectRemovalNotification, objectObjectRemovalNotification.getCause());
                }
            }
        };
```

Finally, I only ever `get` entries to my cache, using `get(K key, Callable<? extends V> valueLoader)`

Here's the problem: with the above code, I am seeing the following log output:

`19:08:03.287 DEBUG [MyCache] - Entry evicted from cache: MyKey[123]=MyRecord@43ee148b - Reason: SIZE`

Why are records being evicted from my cache when I didn't use `maximumSize()` in the CacheBuilder invocation?  I suspect it has something to do with "weight."  If so, what do I need to know about `maxWeight()` to not have cache entries evicted before the expiration time?

**NOTE** I'm aware of [Caches Explained](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained) on the Google Guava site.

Comment: No, this shouldn't happen, regardless of weight considerations.  Can you possibly construct an SSCCE demonstrating the error?

Comment: Additionally, this seems like it might be more appropriate as a bug report than as an SO question.

Comment: Bleh.  Further question: which version of Guava are you using?  I'm looking at the source, and this seems pretty flatly impossible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it possible that your `expirationInterval` is accidentally equal to zero? As `expireAfterAccess` documents, "When `duration` is zero, this method hands off to `maximumSize(0)`."

Comment: Oooh.  I hadn't even thought of that; that seems likely, actually.

Comment: That was it. I overlooked that setting expiration to "0" is synonymous with "maximumSize(0)."  I'm now setting expiration to Long.MAX_VALUE although I suspect that the canonical solution is to use a Ticker.  Thoughts?

Comment: The Ticker is for testing purposes only. Instead of setting expiration to MAX_VALUE, the idea is that you just shouldn't set it at all.